# How to mark some test cases in TYPED_TEST as expected to fail?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am working on a C++ learning project with the dual aims of learning how to write template code as well as learning how to use GoogleTest. My project goal is to implement a working quaternion class along with tests for functionality written using GoogleTest.

My class works pretty well as of now, but I want to mark some GoogleTest test cases as 'Expected To Fail'.
Here's the signature of the relevant constructor for quaternion -

```
template <typename T>
class quaternion {
  template <typename U, typename V, typename W, typename X>
  quaternion(U u, V v, W w, X x);
};
```

I am using GoogleTest to write some TYPED_TEST test cases where I attempt to create a quaternion of a given type **T** with initalizers such as unsigned char, char, etc...

Here's my list of types

```
using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long, float, double, long double>;
```

and here is the test fixture -

```
TYPED_TEST(QuaternionTests, DirectInitialization00) {
  unsigned int i = 5, j = 235, k = 67, l = 82;
  this->SetUp(i, j, k, l);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.a, 5);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.b, 235);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.c, 67);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.d, 82);
}
```

where SetUp just calls the **quaternion** constructor.

Naturally, this test fails when the type of the quaternion is **char** because a **quaternion** cannot hold the value 235 (**unsigned int**) for the member **b**.

My question is - Is there a way to mark the specific combination of **T == char** and **unsigned int** as being 'Expected to Fail' within the confines of the TYPED_TEST macro? Or do I have to switch to the regular TEST macro?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the body of your test to handle this case.  As far as I know, there is no way to mark the *type parameter* as expected to fail.

[In Python’s `pytest` framework, for example, this is possible with `pytest.param(int, marks=pytest.mark.xfail)`.]

It is of course possible to introspect the type parameter and skip the test from the test body.  Google Test [now has a `GTEST_SKIP()` macro](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1544) that I suspect is available from Google Test 1.10.0.

If that macro is not available, you could use the [less explicit `SUCCEED()` macro](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#explicit-success-and-failure), followed by a `return` statement:

```
TYPED_TEST(QuaternionTests, DirectInitialization00) { 
  // Could also check `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` 
  // or `sizeof(T)`.
  using T = typename QuaternionTests::TypeParam;
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>) {
    // with gtest version 1.10.0 and later (?):
    GTEST_SKIP() << "Test is not valid with T equal to `char`.";

    // or with older versions gtest:
    SUCCEED() << "Test is not valid with T equal to `char`.";
    return; 
  }

  unsigned int i = 5, j = 235, k = 67, l = 82;
  this->SetUp(i, j, k, l);

  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.a, 5);  
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.b, 235);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.c, 67);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->q.d, 82);
}
```

Another option is to introduce a *more informative* type parameter that contains the scalar type, along with information about whether to expect success. For example:

```
template <typename T, bool ExpectSuccess = true>
struct QTestParam {
  using type = T;
  using expect_success = std::bool_constant<ExpectSuccess>;
};

using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<
   QTestParam<char, /*ExpectSuccess*/ false>,
   QTestParam<short int>,
   QTestParam<int>,
   QTestParam<long int>,
   QTestParam<float>,
   QTestParam<double>,
>;
```

Then, you could define a test class template like this, which provides access to the Boolean indicator in a nice way:

```
template <typename Param>
struct QuaternionTests : public ::testing::Test {
  using T = Param::type;  // scalar type such as int.

  constexpr static bool ExpectSuccess() {
    return Param::expect_success{};
  }
  constexpr static bool ExpectFailure() {
    return !ExpectSuccess();
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, I think the individual tests would need to implement “skipping“ logic as in the first code snippet:

```
TYPED_TEST(QuaternionTests, DirectInitialization00) {
  constexpr if (ExpectFailure()) {
    GTEST_SKIP();
  }
  // [...]
};
```